# add onchange to select in a wp form

Tags: php, javascript, select

I am using [wp_dropdown_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/) to create a dropdown in the frontend. It creates a nice dropdown select. Now I would like to add `onchange="myFunc()"` to the `<select>`. I need this to trigger some js function when someone selects specific option.

I also took a look into another [relevant codex link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories), could not figure it out. Is there a native wordpress way of doing this ? If not, can you suggest me a solution. I mean something like this.

```
<select id="my_cats" class="postform" name="my_cats" onchange="myFunc()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add any attribute to `<select>` using wordpress filter `wp_dropdown_cats` . 
`wp_dropdown_cats` filter allows you to modify the content of the taxonomy drop-down output.
Try below code.

```
function addAttributeToDropdown($html_content){
  $html_content = str_replace('<select','<select onchange="myFunc()"',$html_content);
  return $html_content; 
}

add_filter('wp_dropdown_cats','addAttributeToDropdown');
```

add this inside your `functions.php` file

Answer (score 1):

Use **JQuery** `change` method

```
$('#my_cats').on('change', function() {
  myFunc();
});

function myFunc() {
     // your function code
  }
```